# CPU 100% busy and computer very slow (from time to time)

Tags: windows-7, cpu, cpu-usage, cpufreq, cpu-temperature

I have a problem that something causes my computer to run at 100% cpu usage but nothing is in general processing. It looks like something is breaking up because suddenly all running processes got 10x usage, so it adds up quickly to 100%. It happened today for the first time.

For example radio player, browser and nbfc run normally at 4%, 2%, 0.5% respectively, but then it jumps to 40%, 30% and 8% and the rest of processes do the same. It blocks all the actions and cause the computer very slow and it stops as sudden as it appears.

I can't find any reasons for that. I suspect it's starts often when I play video. Can I test it somehow? I don't know what could I check. I checked temperatures but they looks normal (except some weird "Temp3" which jumps and shows 0deg-127deg all the time, but maybe it's some software bug.

I use Win7 which normally is very fast and a laptop is [HP 8440p](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-8440p-notebook-pc/4095872). Anyone got such issues??

**EDIT**

I found some workaround and possible the reason of my problem. The laptop goes in "slow mode". I don't know why, but maybe because of this failed "temp3" reading, maybe the sensor is damaged. The motherboard probably doesn't have switch for this, so I forced to disable this mode using `ThrottleStop` program. It's risky, but I only turn it on for a while with multiplier parameter set to maximum. After this it works well for an hour or several hours. Later I need to reply this procedure because "slow mode" is back.

It would be great to remove this issue with sensor but I even can't find where is it located, one of 13 (probably) in this computer, if it really causes this problem.

**EDIT**

The problem still continues. It was 2 days ok while that "temp3" reading was 0 deg. Now it's again 127 deg and the "slow mode" again turns on. It's probably not sensor issue because it's connected with the problem. It keeps all temperatures higher over 10 degrees. I cleaned everything inside laptop and changed pasta on CPU but it's still there. Only the conductivity to radiator is now better so CPU can't be even below 40 deg.

I really don't know why it was all right for 2 days and where physically this temperature occurs. Can't find any documentation on that.

**EDIT**

I found out what slows my cpu. Its clock mode falls below 100%. It suddebly gets 12.5% and the only way to get back cpu to normal speed is to check "clock mode" box in `throttleStop` program. This should work automatically, like it was before, but don't know how to set it in the system. The FID field (multiplier) also falls down, but it slows computer in "normal" way - doesn't freeze it.

Comment: Simple testing: start [Performance Monitor](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2229240&seqNum=2), then start a video. Repeat with a few different vids to see if this happens every time. Once you know this, to get help on figuring out how to address the issue you need to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1775419/edit) your question to add more context. For example how do you start the vid and from where? Starting one on VLC and streaming one over the internet are 2 different things, and in internet streaming the stream source site is important to know.

Comment: Use [Sysinternals/Microsoft procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon). See what your computer is doing right then.  You will need to figure out how to filter to get the results you are looking for but your problem should become clear once you do.